# How to I increment a single element in an array?

Tags: php

I have the PHP code below:

```
<?php

    $length = $_GET["length"];
    $maxValue = $_GET["maxValue"];
    $distribution = array();

    for($j = 0; $j < $maxValue; $j++) {
        $distribution[j] = 5;
    }

    $x = 0;
    $x++;

    for($j = 0; $j < $maxValue; $j++) {
        echo $distribution[j] , " ";
    }

    echo $x;

?>
```

`$x` starts as 0 and is incremented by 1. However, just below `$x` is incremented, I am also incrementing the first element of the "distribution" array - `$distribution[0]`. And it's not working. It worked fine when I was initializing the elements (set them to 5).

Any ideas on why it might now be working? I am probably referencing the array element wrong. But this seems inconsistent.

Comment: `$distribution[j]` -> `$distribution[$j]` Dollar sign missing

Comment: Also I don't really see what your question is. Means what your current output is and what you expected to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `$distribution[j]` -> php doesn't understand the `j` as a variable - but rather as an *undefined constant*

It looks like you are trying to say `$distribution[$j]` - which is partially -why your increments aren't working - -

The other reason would be that you aren't ever calling `$distribution[$j]++` --- so there is no incrementation happening...